# Mustn't do_action be accompanied with a function?

Tags: actions

Lets say we have  a do_action like this:

```
do_action('some_action');
```

Doesn't this mean that there has to be a `some_action()` function somewhere in the wordpress like this for example:

```
function some_action(){
   /* blah blah blah*/
}
```

My question comes from a `do_action()` at the storefront theme of woocommerce that has a line in header.php like this:

```
do_action( 'storefront_header' );
```

But I haven't been able to find any `storefront_header()` function so I started wondering perhaps not all do_actions are coming with a function of their own. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The param used in `do_action` isn't a function is just a tag that represents the action called, the proper way to use an action is attaching functions with `add_action`.

You can learn more from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/

Answer (score 3):

No.

The `some_action` in `do_action( 'some_action' );` is an *action hook*, and allows you to cause actions to happen at a specific point in time during WordPress's lifecycle. If an action hook happens to share a name with a function, it's a coincidence (or often a convenience).

From the glossary:

> … an Action is a PHP function that is executed at specific points throughout the WordPress Core.
>
> Developers can create a custom Action using the Action API to add or remove code from an existing Action by specifying any existing Hook. This process is called "hooking".

—[Glossary: Action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action)

Action hooks (and their cousins, filter hooks) are part of WordPress's rich [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look in `storefront/inc/storefront-template-hooks.php` see https://github.com/woocommerce/storefront/blob/1790927f8cab022bc96847fb0efc4f2f2ff6b2aa/inc/storefront-template-hooks.php

You can see the action in here, and the relevant functions (and order):

```
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_skip_links',                       0 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_site_branding',                    20 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_secondary_navigation',             30 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper',       42 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation',               50 );
add_action( 'storefront_header', 'storefront_primary_navigation_wrapper_close', 68 );
```

With this first one, selected for example, the function here is `storefront_skip_links`, which is in `storefront/inc/storefront-template-functions.php` (line 279 at time of writing!) and looks like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'storefront_skip_links' ) ) {
    /**
     * Skip links
     *
     * @since  1.4.1
     * @return void
     */
    function storefront_skip_links() {
        ?>
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#site-navigation"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to navigation', 'storefront' ); ?></a>
        <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'storefront' ); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you to understand how this works in practice!